# gethostbyaddr too slow

Tags: delphi, network-programming, delphi-2007

I use the following code, results are correct, but `gethostbyaddr` takes around 30 seconds.

```
function IPAddrToName(IPAddr: string): string;  
var   
  SockAddrIn: TSockAddrIn;   
  HostEnt: PHostEnt;   
  WSAData: TWSAData;   
begin   
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData);   
  SockAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PChar(IPAddr));   
  HostEnt := gethostbyaddr(@SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);   
  if HostEnt <> nil then   
    Result := StrPas(Hostent^.h_name)   
  else   
    Result := '';   
end;
```

Comment: Usually, yes, but we won't know for sure until we get timings from the code. Otherwise I would have nudged it over to SU straight away.

Comment: Compare a `nslookup` with this call, see if it differs much. If it does not, then it is definitely a DNS issue.

Answer (score 3):

That's unlikely to be an issue with your code (unless `WSAStartup` is particularly slow).

The *first* thing I would do is to output the time (preferably to the millisecond, with `GetTickCount`, I think) in between each of those lines in your code, to find out exactly where the time is being spent.

The `gethostbyaddr` may well have to go out to a remote DNS machine to resolve the IP address into a hostname.

If your network is set up badly, or the DNS server containing that address is in the remote regions of the Tibetan mountains for example, resolution *will* take some time.

From your command line, enter:

```
nslookup x.x.x.x
```

(where `x.x.x.x` is the IP address you're interested in) and see how long that takes.

Based on your comment between the ruler lines below:

---

I am working on LAN with just 3 machines. Also that network is not connected to the internet. It takes 16 secs (+/- some millisecs) for only the line:

```
HostEnt := gethostbyaddr(@SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);
```

while:

```
GetHostByName(PChar(HostName));
```

is instantaneous. Below is the output of Ping (instant output) and nslookup:

```
c:\> ping 192.168.1.22
Reply from 192.168.1.22: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Packets:
    Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)

c:\> nslookup 192.168.1.22
DNS request timed out.
```

---

I think your problem is with that timeout. It appears your network is set up okay for DNS name resolution but not IP reverse resolution.

When you just type `nslookup`, it should show you your DNS server that it's trying to use and this will probably give you a clue.

```
c:\pax> nslookup
Default Server:  pax01.neveryoumind.com
Address:  9.190.230.75
```

It may be that resolving names to IP addresses doesn't go out through DNS but is instead handled with local information.

That's about as much help as I can give you with the current information. Since this now seems very much a SuperUser question now rather than StackOverflow, I'll nudge it over to there.

Comment: I am working on LAN with just 3 machines. Also that network is not connected to the internet.

It takes 16 secs (+- some millisecs) for only this line 
HostEnt := gethostbyaddr(@SockAddrIn.sin_addr.S_addr, 4, AF_INET);


GetHostByName(PChar(HostName)); 
is instant (http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/internet/get_computer_name_from_ip_address.html)

Below is the output of Ping (instant output) and nslookup
c:\>Ping 192.168.1.22
Reply from 192.168.1.22: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

c:\>nslookup 192.168.1.22

DNS request timed out.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this site.
How do I link to Superuser ?

Comment: @Allan, at the bottom of this page is a link superuser.com - you can re-ask your question there, providing a link to this one so they can check out the answer. If 5 people vote to close this one as "belongs on su", it will move automatically.

Comment: Although, come to think of it, it probably belongs on serverfault since it's network-related (link also below).

Comment: I guess if he has just three PC in a LAN he has no DNS server at all, especially if they are not connected to the Internet through a router that takes the DHCP/DNS role as well. Pinging an IP address obviously works, and Windows will try some other way to resolve host names (i.e. netbios broadcasts).

Answer (score 1):

Windows attempts different ways to perform host name resolution depending on the way your hosts and LAN are configured. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727005.aspx.
You should not test that code in a LAN which is not correctly configured, either using a DNS server (or at least a WINS one) or correct hosts files. Otherwise you could not get the result you'd expect in a properly configured LAN.